Исполнение корутины в конструкторе класса
У меня есть класс, в котором мне после его инициализации необходимо произвести авторизацию на сайте, чтобы использовать  другие методы. При этом я не хочу, чтобы пользователь использовал дополнительные методы типа auth(), init() и т.д.
Я хочу сделать по аналогии с redis-py, там же не происходит никакой авторизации через какой-то метод типа auth(). Примерно таким образом осуществляется работа с Redis:
import redis.asyncio as redis

client = redis.Redis()
print(f"Ping successful: {await client.ping()}")
await client.aclose()

Никаких допольнительных методов для авторизации мы не видим.
И, как мы знаем, использовать корутины в конструкторе __init__() нельзя.
Отсюда вопрос, как можно обойти такое? Лично я делал метод в классе, который каждый раз использовался в методе примерно так:
    async def get_marks(self) -> dict[str, list[Mark]]:
    await self.__execute_auth()
    return await Marks(self._http_page).get_marks()

async def get_schedule(self):
    pass

async def get_session_data(self) -> User | None:
    await self.__execute_auth()
    return self._login_service.session_data

Через __execute_auth() я проводил проверку, выполнена ли авторизация, если нет, то авторизовываемся, если да, то возвращаем None.

Вешаем декоратор на нужные методы -> авторизация происходит только при вызове метода, а не в __init__ -> в самом декораторе вызываем авторизацию и вешаем флаг если успех. И того авторизация сработает только один раз (в случае успеха) при вызове любого из нужных методов. И дополнительных методов вводить не нужно.
